# Error when try to connect phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

In my Local host when try to connect phpmyadmin I have an error like this:

> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
>   rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
>   password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
>   the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

How to correct the issue ? please help me.

Comment: well, can you post the way you connect (omitting the *real* IP/username/password ) ?

Comment: are you opening it directly or from a php file?

Comment: username:root and no password set for it

Comment: open it using http://localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: make sure you are connecting properly. Are the username/password/host you're entering correct? did you check the $servers variable in the config.inc.php file in the phpmyadmin root directory?

Answer (score 0):

try to erase all cookies that regard phpmhadmin. I always have this problem when I install it and this is the first step... have you changed the username/password from another program? i.e mySQL workbench?